# Spring Cloud Stream from Kafka to Rabbit

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to send messages from kafka's topic to multipe rabbitMQ queues using Kafka message key as a routing key for rabbitmq message.
The pipeline looks like this: kafka's topic -> spring cloud stream application -> rabbitmq

RabbitMQ settings

Exchange type: direct. All queues are binded to the Exchange, routing keys and queues names are the same.

SCS config

```
  cloud:
    stream:
      default-binder: rabbit
      function:
        definition: upstreamProcessor
      bindings:
        upstreamProcessor-in-0:
          destination: here is the kafka topic
          group: ms-upstream-provider
          binder: kafka
        upstreamProcessor-out-0:
          destination: here is the rabbitMQ exchange name
          binder: rabbit
      rabbit.bindings.upstreamProcessor-out-0.producer:
        exchangeType: direct
```

Using upstreamProcessor function I'm reading incoming messages, create new message and send to rabbitMQ.

But I don't understand how to add routing key to the each outgoing messages? I've got a lot of different queues (> 6000) and I want to set routing keys in code not in settings
In documentation and on the site I didn't find how to programmaticaly set the routing key

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

```
public Function<Message<String>, Message<JsonNode>> upstreamProcessor() {
    return message -> {
        try {
            JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(message.getPayload());
            String routingKey= message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY).toString();
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(node)
                    .setHeader("routingKey", routingKey)
                    .build();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the routing key in the code as you have done, i.e., `.setHeader("routingKey," routingKey).` Then you need to set the `routingKeyExpression` on the producer binding via configuration.
`spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.upstreamProcessor-out-0.producer.routing-key-expression=headers['routingKey']`.

This way any outbound publishing via the `upstreamProcessor-out-0` binding will consult the `routingKey` header as the routing key used by the AMQP outbound endpoint. Note that the header name could be anything - it doesn't have to be `routingKey`.

Comment: Thank you, Soby. I'll try and tell about results